# UIWebView with Outlet and Delegate causes NSUnknownKeyException

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

I am having an issue getting UIWebView as an outlet.  I've done my research, here are the steps I've taken.

Using XCode 5.0.1

- Created a ViewController named WebViewController with XIB
- Verified fileowner is WebViewController
- added a UIWebView  to the xib
- set UIWebView delegate to FileOwner WebViewController
- modified WebViewController.h, adding
- Adding the following methods to WebViewController.m

  1. `(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`
  2. `(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`
  3. `(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error`
  4. `(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`
- Create an outlet from UIWebView to myWebView (in the .m file)

As soon as I push the WebViewController I get a NSUnknownKeyException on myWebView.

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<WebViewController 0x19ff75a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myWebView.'
```

IMPORTANT: If I merely remove the outlet to myWebView then I can push the WebViewController fine.  Of course I cannot modify the UIWebView though with no outlet.

Any idea what is going on here?  I get the same issue in a new/blank project as well.

UPDATE:
- So WebViewController.xib FIleOwner custom class is: WebViewController, verified in InterfaceBuilder
- Creation at runtime is like this

```
 [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];
```

- Breakpoint set at initWithNibName in WebViewController.m never fires.

Comment: can you show the full error message ?

Comment: updated with error message

Comment: I don't see your code for your outlet in `WebViewController`, will you add that?

Answer (score 0):

from the error message, seems that your `UIWebView` in xib is already connected to outlet named `myWebView`, but the outlet variable is not in .m or .h; try to right click on your `UIWebView` in xib file, and remove the connected outlet.

## EDIT

if that trick didn't work. try to remove `myWebView` manually from the xib. here the steps :

- right click on xib, click `Open As`, click on `Source Code`
- you will get xml code of the xib, try to find (ctrl + f) using `myWebView` keyword
- remove it

Comment: Yes I realize that is what this error message usually means but this is clearly not the cause this time.  Removing the outlet makes it work, adding it back in fresh fails on NSUnknownKeyException.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it

Comment: I don't think you are understand.  I can already remove the outlet, no issues there.  Removing the outlet makes the exception go away.  I need the outlet however.  Adding it back in causes exception.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added your WebViewController to your target. Tap on WebViewController.m check Target Membership. Make sure checkbox is selected.

[image]

Comment: I have verified they are in the build targets.  Also as since merely by removing the UIWebView to myWebView outlet I can push this WebViewController just fine.

Comment: Do you have another outlets in that XIB connected with controller?

Comment: WebViewController.xib has only a UIWebView.  The UIWebView has 1 outlet, delegate->File Owner and 1 referencing outlet myWebView->File Owner.

Comment: I believe this is connected with target. Try to Clean project. If will not help try to create Controller and Xib again.

Comment: Cleaned 100 times before I posted on SO.

Comment: There is another point too. You do not need to verify fileOwner when you are creating Xib with controller

Answer (score 0):

So I changed the name of the files after discovering this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/uicatalog/listings/ViewControllers_WebViewController_m.html

Now everything works perfect.  The steps I listed in the question work just fine to create a UIWebView.